# том чтобы при наведении на монетку она подсвечивается как купюра и при клике на монетку она должна исчезать

Tags: javascript

Объясните пожалуйста как мне сделать так, чтобы монетки при нажатии на них светились и пропадали.
Если не сложно объяснить на примере.

Помогите Сделать так чтобы монетки со сдачи подсвечивались при наведении

И пропадали при клике.

Программу писала давно и уже подзабыла .

```js
let money = document.getElementById("money");
let displayInfo = document.getElementById("displayInfo");
let bills = document.querySelectorAll("img[src$='rub.jpg']");
let bill_acc = document.querySelector("img[src$='bill_acc.jpg']");
let balance = document.getElementById("balance");
//let test = document.getElementById("test");

function getCoffee(price, name) {
  if (money.value >= price) {
    money.value -= price; //money.value - price;
    balance.innerHTML = `Баланс: ${money.value} руб.`;
    startProgressBar(name);

    // console.log("Ваш " + name + " готов!");
  } else {
    displayInfo.innerHTML = "У Вас не хватает денег для покупки " + name;
    // console.log("Нет денег, значит нет и кофе");
  }
}

function startProgressBar(coffeeName) {
  let i = 0;
  let progressBar = document.querySelector(".progress-bar");
  progressBar.parentElement.hidden = false;

  function progress() {
    i++;
    progressBar.style.width = i + "%";

    if (i == 100) {
      clearInterval(timerId);
      progressBar.parentElement.hidden = true;
      progressBar.style.width = 0 + "%";
      displayInfo.innerHTML = `Ваш ${coffeeName} готов!`;
    } else if (i == 50) {
      displayInfo.innerHTML = `Напиток ${coffeeName} почти готов... `;
    }
  }
  let timerId = setInterval(progress, 100);
}

function getChange(num) {
  let coin;
  let top = getRandom(0, changeBox.getBoundingClientRect().height - 75);
  let left = getRandom(0, changeBox.getBoundingClientRect().width - 75);
  if (num >= 10) coin = 10;
  else if (num >= 5) coin = 5;
  else if (num >= 2) coin = 2;
  else if (num >= 1) coin = 1;
  console.log(coin);
  changeBox.innerHTML += `<img src="/img/${coin}rub.png" style="top:${top}px; left:${left}px">`; //changeBox.innerHTML + `<img src="/img/${coin}rub.png">`;
  if (num - coin !== 0) {
    getChange(num - coin);
  }
}

for (bill of bills) {
  bill.onmousedown = function(e) {
    bill = e.currentTarget;
    bill.style.position = "absolute";
    bill.style.zIndex = 1000;
    bill.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";

    //Устанавливаем слушателя на событие mousemove
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", moveAt);

    //Удаляем слушателя по событию onmouseup
    bill.onmouseup = function() {
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", moveAt);
      bill.style.zIndex = 1;

      //Получаем координаты купюр и приемника
      let bill_top = bill.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      let bill_left = bill.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      let bill_right = bill.getBoundingClientRect().right;
      let bill_acc_top = bill_acc.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      let bill_acc_left = bill_acc.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      let bill_acc_right = bill_acc.getBoundingClientRect().right;
      let bill_acc_bottom =
        bill_acc.getBoundingClientRect().bottom -
        (bill_acc.getBoundingClientRect().height / 3) * 2;
      //Проверяем и сопоставляем координаты
      if (
        bill_top > bill_acc_top &&
        bill_left > bill_acc_left &&
        bill_right < bill_acc_right &&
        bill_top < bill_acc_bottom
      ) {
        //bill.hidden = true;
        bill.classList.add("animated");
        setTimeout(function() {
          bill.hidden = true;
        }, 1800);
        money.value = +money.value + +bill.dataset.billValue; //Записываем значение купюры в инпут
        balance.innerHTML = `Баланс: ${money.value} руб.`;
      }
    };

    //Движение и позиционирование купюры
    function moveAt(event) {
      let x = event.clientX - 149;
      let y = event.clientY - 62;
      bill.style.top = y + "px";
      bill.style.left = x + "px";
    }
    //Отменяем стандартное поведение браузера
    bill.ondragstart = function() {
      return false;
    };
  };
}

function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

// bills.forEach(function (num) {
//  num.onmousedown = function () {
//      console.log("Событие onmousedown");
//  };
// });
// for (let i = 0; i < bills.length; i++) {
//  bills[i].onmousedown = function (e) {
//      bills[i] = e.currentTarget;
//      bills[i].style.position = "absolute";
//      bills[i].style.zIndex = 1000;

//      //Устанавливаем слушателя на событие mousemove
//      document.addEventListener("mousemove", moveAt);

//      //Удаляем слушателя по событию onmouseup
//      bills[i].onmouseup = function () {
//          document.removeEventListener("mousemove", moveAt);
//          bills[i].style.zIndex = 1;
//      };

//      //Движение и позиционирование купюры
//      function moveAt(event) {
//          let x = event.clientX - 75;
//          let y = event.clientY - 75;
//          bills[i].style.top = y + "px";
//          bills[i].style.left = x + "px";
//      }
//      //Отменяем стандартное поведение браузера
//      bills[i].ondragstart = function () {
//          return false;
//      };
//  };
// }

function oldgetChange(num) {
  if (num >= 10) {
    console.log(10);
    oldgetChange(num - 10);
  } else if (num >= 5) {
    console.log(5);
    oldgetChange(num - 5);
  } else if (num >= 2) {
    console.log(2);
    oldgetChange(num - 2);
  } else if (num >= 1) {
    console.log(1);
    oldgetChange(num - 1);
  } else {
    console.log("Вся сдача выдана!");
  }
}

function ternGetChange(value) {
  let coin =
    value >= 10 ? 10 : value >= 5 ? 5 : value >= 2 ? 2 : value >= 1 ? 1 : "Вся сдача выдана";
  console.log(coin);
  if (value - coin !== 0) ternGetChange(value - coin);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Mulish", sans-serif;
  height: 95vh;
  background-image: url(img2/cofee2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.coffee_btn {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  /* border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: blue; */
  border-top: 40px solid transparent;
  border-left: 80px solid rgb(64, 151, 68);
  border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.coffee_btn:hover {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 40px solid transparent;
  border-left: 80px solid rgb(62, 105, 68);
  border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
}

.coffee_txt>span {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-size: clamp(1.2rem, calc(1rem + 2vw), 2rem);
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-left: 2.5rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.coffee_txt {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.096);
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(170, 168, 165, 0.644);
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}


/* #money {
                    margin-top: 0.5rem;
                    margin-left: 1.5rem;
                } */

#display {
  width: 100%;
  height: 16.5rem;
  background-color: rgba(17, 154, 17, 0.7);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

img[src$="rub.jpg"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: contrast(150%);
}

.animated {
  animation-name: hide-bill;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
}

@keyframes hide-bill {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg) rotateY(1deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg) rotateY(40deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#changeBox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(86, 107, 121, 0.7);
  border: 2px solid black;
}

img[src$="rub.png"] {
  width: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon-coffee.png" />
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mulish:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous" />


<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row mb-5">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="row coffee_txt">
        <div class="coffee_btn" onclick="getCoffee(63, 'Латте')"></div>
        <span>Латте - 63 руб.</span>
      </div>
      <div class="row coffee_txt">
        <div class="coffee_btn" onclick="getCoffee(74, 'Мокко')"></div>
        <span>Мокко - 74 руб.</span>
      </div>
      <div class="row coffee_txt">
        <div class="coffee_btn" onclick="getCoffee(77, 'Капучино')"></div>
        <span>Капучино  - 77 руб.</span>
      </div>
      <div class="row coffee_txt">
        <div class="coffee_btn" onclick="getCoffee(98, 'Раф')"></div>
        <span>Раф- 98 руб.</span>
      </div>
      <div class="row coffee_txt">
        <div class="coffee_btn" onclick="getCoffee(195, 'Гляссе')"></div>
        <span> Гляссе - 195 руб.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="row mt-2">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div id="display">
            <p id="displayInfo">Внесите деньги.</p>
            <p id="balance">Баланс: 0 руб.</p>
            <div class="progress" hidden>
              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg mt-3" onclick="getChange(money.value)">
                                        Получить сдачу
                                    </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="hidden" id="money" />
          <img src="/img/bill_acc.jpg" alt="" />
          <div id="changeBox" class="mt-3"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img src="/img/50rub.jpg" alt="" data-bill-value="50" />
  <img src="/img/100rub.jpg" alt="" data-bill-value="100" />
  <img src="/img/500rub.jpg" alt="" data-bill-value="500" />
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: старайся давай более содержательные заголовки.

Comment: Исправила так понятнее ?

Comment: уже лучше чем было.

Comment: Сможете помочь я Уже все перепробовала но программа ломается. Судя скинула рабочий код. Я лично вспоминаю для себя . Получилось подсветить деньги . Но чтобы все вместе не работает

Comment: так какая проблема-то в итоге? _делать так чтобы монетки при нажатии на них светились и пропадали_? или что-то обнулять? что значит _программа ломается_?

Comment: Монетки  а то я не могу уже с ними биться если можно то на моем коде

Comment: убери все что не относится к вопросу. И попробуй четко ограничить - какую конкретно проблему ты хочешь решить: сейчас как минимум три проблемы, что-то подсветить, что-то убрать, что-то не работает вместе с чем-то.

Comment: Исправила помогите пожалуйста !!!

Comment: О каких монетах речь? Что нужно сделать в твоем примере, чтобы увидеть проблему?

Comment: сможите помочь помочь

Comment: @Ника получилось решить проблему ?

Comment: @Ника, вместо удаления кода, отредактируй его так, чтобы сразу была видна твоя проблема. Иначе вопрос становится непонятным и обесценивает уже данный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Что-бы удалить монету при клтке на неё, то при её создание добавляем ей событья `onclick` которая вызывает фукнцию для удаление.

Для подсветки монетки добавляем ей класс, у меня `coin-hover`, и этому классу добавляем селектор `:hover` для применение к нему стилью когда мы наводим на класс.

Вот часть кода

```js
const changeBox = document.querySelector('.test');

function getChange(num) {
  let coin;
  let top = Math.random() * 425;
  let left = Math.random() * 425;
  if (num >= 10) coin = 10;
  else if (num >= 5) coin = 5;
  else if (num >= 2) coin = 2;
  else if (num >= 1) coin = 1;
  changeBox.innerHTML += `<div style="top:${top}px; left:${left}px" onclick="removeCoin(this)" class="coin-hover">${coin}</div>`;

  if (num - coin !== 0) {
    getChange(num - coin);
  }
}
//Функций для удаления
function removeCoin(elem) {
  elem.remove();
}

getChange(12);
```

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.coin-hover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 32px;
  transition: .25s;
  font-family: consolas;
  background-color: royalblue;
}

.coin-hover:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 24px 8px rgba(208, 92, 92, 1),
              inset 0 0 24px 8px rgba(208, 92, 92, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не подскажите а в моем коде я это как все оформляю не подскажите ?

Comment: @Ника я добавил фото как это должно выглядить для вашего кода

Comment: @Ника надеюсь стиль CSS вы можете добавить :P

Comment: Не подскажите у меня не пропадает по клику

Comment: @Ника добавьте ваш новый код на вашем хостинге 0207.napli.ru/coffee-machine.html )

Comment: я сделала все как на фотографии но у меня не работает клик

Comment: @Ника я извиняюсь но `onlick` не пишется `oniclick`, у вас там опечатка)

Comment: Все получилось спасибо

Comment: если это вам помогло, можете отметить ответ как правильный нажав галочку слева )